# Import iBooks folder?

Tags: itunes, ipad, books

I was running iTunes 11 under Snow Leopard and syncing to an old iPad, the very first one.

Now, the latest iPad (pro) needs iTunes 11, which needed higher than Snow Leo, so I'm running it under Yosemite. All apps seem to have moved ok, but the iBooks were all left behind.

Is there a simple way to import the folder of iBooks to iTunes 12 to load to the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Since Mavericks, iBooks is the app that handles the books/PDFs, you can "add to library" the books right from the old iTunes folder, and then sync to your iPad.

It offers features to handle books that iTunes didn't, such as adding categories and organizing from the application on the Mac, instead of doing it from your iPad.